# fckeditor on mediawiki 1.16 doesn't show when using rtl languages

Tags: fckeditor, mediawiki

I have mediawiki 1.16 + fck editor (current snapshot).
If the wiki is set to english everything works fine but on hebrew and arabic the editor does not show, only the regular toolbar shows. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encountered that too, and had to solve by myself :(.
Solution is here:
https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=25653

Comment: Great! So I take it's going to be fixed in the next version? You have any idea when that's coming? If it takes too long I'll just change it myself, but I prefer not to mess with the code.

Comment: Have no idea, hope they will add it soon

Answer (score 0):

Have you even got the those [language files](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/language-selection-fckeditor/)?

Comment: Yes, they're all there under editor/lang.
I also tried overriding the autodetect language, still nothing.

Comment: Hmmm - is this the case with all browsers? Which ones (and versions) have you tested? (There is a known defect about this which is now solved: http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/6068)

Comment: Tested on internet explorer and chrome.
Note that I'm not using that version of ckeditor, i'm using this version of fckeditor: http://svn.wikimedia.org/svnroot/mediawiki/trunk/extensions/FCKeditor/

And thanks for the help

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the editor itself, but in the code that integrates it with mediawiki.

Comment: @Uri - OK, then I'm out of ideas but maybe the details you've added will help someone else answer. Good luck.